# Handle multiple errors in nested dictionary/lists

Tags: python, json, loops, error-handling, nested

I want to loop through a large number of json files (json string1,2,3 etc.) with a lot of nested lists and dictionaries. So I need to handle both KeyErrors and IndexErrors in case a value is missing. Example of json structure that is entering my loop:

Json string 1: 'questions': {'39860004': [{'15920003': 2.6, '25860009': 1.6, '11990005': [{'name': 'croton'}], '48090004': [{'name': 'Mark'}], '11980002': 0.6, '40310003': [{'name': 'croton_macrostachyus'}], '40300005': 5.3, '5900005': 0.29, '21860001': 0.45, '50110005': 0.7, '53213': {'lat': 1.198, 'long': 32.767, 'elev': None, 'code': None}, '54040005': 2.5, '2345677': [{'name': 'croton'}]}

So for each of the json, I need to loop through each of the nested items and extract the values.

In order to do so I am using a for loop:

```
for x in json string 1['questions']['39860004']:
   value 1 = x['15920003']
   value 2 = x['25860009']
   etc.
```

Now, I need to handle both KeyErrors (for missing dictionary items) and IndexErrors (for missing lists). How can I do this best to make the code robust? The issue is that when a value is not found in the json, I still need to stay in the loop to find the other values.

I tried:

```
for x in json string 1['questions']['39860004']:
   Try:
     value 1 = x['15920003']
   except IndexError:
     value 1 = ''
   else KeyError:
     value 1 = ''
   Etc....
```

However, besides I get an error on this syntax, this approach does not seem consistent. I could also create a new 'for loop' for every item handling Key- and IndexErrors seperately, but this does not seems elegant to me. Any advise how this can be covered efficient (and elegant)?

Comment: The `else` should be an `except`, too. You can capture both cases at once tho: `except (IndexError, KeyError):`

Comment: Never had such a fast response before (I was still editing my question while you gave the answer already...) and with a good solution! Many thanks. This worked. Sometimes the solution is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can except multiple errors at once by using `except (KeyError, Indexerror) as e:`

If you want to except errors and react to them differently, you can nest "try and except" inside another.

```
try:
     try:
         <code>
     except error 1:
         <error handling 1>
except error 2:
     <error handling 2>
```